# Difference between NVMe queuing interface and PCIe queuing interface

Tags: storage, pci, scsi

Can any please let me know the difference between the two.

Please provoide relavent links if any .

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning this stuff but from what I am reading:
The maximum size of the Admin Completion Queue is 4096 entries. This is a 0’s based value. The maximum size of the Admin Submission Queue is 4096 entries. This is a 0’s based value. (NVM-Express 1.1)

however The maximum number of elements is 255 for administrator IQs and administrator OQs. http://www.t10.org/cgi-bin/ac.pl

so I am sure there are lots of other differences

Answer (score 0):

PCIe Queuing Interface (PQI) was a storage protocol with queues, similar to NVMe.

Nowadays NVMe thrives, and PQI is dead.

---

Some differences are:

- NVMe defines both queues organization and command sets. PQI defines only queues organization, entries in this queue are arbitrary. It had an upper-level protocol to carry SCSI commands over it, which was defined separately (called SOP - SCSI over PQI)
- NVMe uses fixed size command entries with uniform layout, one per queue slot. PQI could use multiple queue slots for one command
- PQI used producer and consumer indices, they were similar to NVMe doorbells  in some sense, but required more operations to service a command
- NVMe employs PRPs to address data, later on SGLs were added as an alternative, PQI used SGLs only from the start